# JsonPatch to preserve naming of properties (camel-cased)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, json-patch

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch` which I've added via NuGet from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch/) and got stuck when trying to match my properties back on API-side.

Is there any way to preserve the camel-case naming of my properties when serializing/deserializing.

My simplified object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string MyCamelCaseProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When creating a `JsonPatchDocument<MyObject>` with the operation `Replace` I get the path `/mycamelcaseproperty`. But, on API-side I want to make some sort of switch-case by the `path` property (without the leading '/') like

```
var normalizedPath = operation.path.Replace("/", string.Empty)
switch(normalizedPath)
{
    case nameof(MyObject.MyCamelCaseProperty):
        // do replacement of the MyCamelCaseProperty property
        break;
}
```

The question is: Can the camel-case be preserved or do I have to find another way on how to match the property-names I have to do actions on? 
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is ´NormalizedPath´ defined ? I have search the Repo https://github.com/aspnet/JsonPatch but there the case preserving Path property is defined for JsonPatch operations. Perhaps in NoarmalizedPath is some kind of LowerCase logic defined.

Comment: Sorry. The `NormalizedPath` is just the path-name without the leading '/' to just get the property-name. Will update my question

Comment: @rboe: Seems like the version from nuget (1.1.0) is not the same as within aspnet.core, right?